# Flutter - BoxConstraints forces an infinite height

Tags: flutter

I am trying to code a small flutter project and I am falling on this error and don't understand why. I have tried all the online solution but still getting the error. It occurs every time I click on the delete in the showCupertinoDialog it shows this error without crashing the app

```
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

These invalid constraints were provided to _RenderColoredBox's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
  RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=358.0, h=Infinity)
```

And below is my code

```
class DashboardRestaurant extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardRestaurant({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String id = 'dashboard_restaurant';

  @override
  _DashboardRestaurantState createState() => _DashboardRestaurantState();
}

class _DashboardRestaurantState extends State<DashboardRestaurant> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> activities = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance.collection('activities')
      .where('Type', isEqualTo: 'Restaurant')
      .orderBy('ts', descending: true)
      .snapshots();

  bool showSpinner = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LoadingOverlay(
      isLoading: showSpinner,
      opacity: 0.5,
      color: Colors.green,
      progressIndicator: const CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green),
      ),
      child:Column(
                children:[
                  AddButton(
                    title: 'Restaurants',
                    addLabel: 'Add Restaurant',
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, RestaurantMainForm.id);
                    },),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 16.0,
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    color: Colors.white70,
                    height:40.0,
                  ),
                  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: activities,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      final data = snapshot.requireData;
                      if(data != null){
                        return ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(
                              width: 360,
                            height: 250,
                          ),
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              itemCount: data.size,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        CircleAvatar(
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                          radius: 40,
                                          child:data.docs[index] == null ? Image.asset('assets/images/image.png') : Image.network(
                                            data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl'],
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          ) ,
                                        ),
                                        Text( data.docs[index]['Name'], style:const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

                                        ),
                                        if(Responsive.isWeb(context))
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            width: 50,
                                          ),
                                        Responsive.isWeb(context) ? ButtonBlue(
                                          addLabel: 'View Restaurant',
                                          color: Colors.green,
                                          onPressed: (){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                                              return ViewRestaurant(
                                                restaurant: data.docs[index],
                                              );
                                            }));
                                          },
                                          icon: const Icon(IconData(61161, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
                                        ) : InkWell(
                                          onTap: (){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                                              return ViewRestaurant(
                                                restaurant: data.docs[index],
                                              );
                                            }));
                                          },
                                          child: const Icon(IconData(61161, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
                                        ),
                                        Responsive.isWeb(context) ? ButtonBlue(
                                          addLabel: 'Delete Restaurant',
                                          color: Colors.red,
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            showDialog(
                                                context: context,
                                                builder: (BuildContext context){
                                                  return ShowDialog(
                                                    deleteFunction: () async{
                                                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
                                                        FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl3']).delete().then((value) {
                                                          FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl2']).delete().then((value){
                                                            FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl']).delete();
                                                          });
                                                        });
                                                        myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference);
                                                      });
                                                    },
                                                    dialogTitle: "Delete",
                                                    dialogContent: "Do you really want to delete ${data.docs[index]['Name']} restaurant?",
                                                  );
                                                });
                                          },
                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_outline,),
                                        ): InkWell(
                                          onTap: (){
                                            if(defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS){
                                              showCupertinoDialog(
                                                  context: context,
                                                  builder: (BuildContext context){
                                                    return ShowDialog(
                                                      deleteFunction: () async{
                                                        setState(() {
                                                          showSpinner = true;
                                                        });
                                                        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
                                                          FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl3']).delete().then((value) {
                                                            FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl2']).delete().then((value){
                                                              FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl']).delete();
                                                            });
                                                          });
                                                          myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference);
                                                        }).then((value) {
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            showSpinner = false;
                                                          });
                                                          showToast(message: 'Deleted Successfully', color: Colors.green);
                                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                                        });
                                                      },
                                                      dialogTitle: "Delete",
                                                      dialogContent: "Do you really want to delete ${data.docs[index]['Name']} restaurant?",
                                                    );
                                                  });
                                            }
                                            else {
                                              showDialog(
                                                  context: context,
                                                  builder: (BuildContext context){
                                                    return ShowDialog(
                                                      deleteFunction: () async{
                                                        setState(() {
                                                          showSpinner = true;
                                                        });
                                                        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction myTransaction) async {
                                                          FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl3']).delete().then((value) {
                                                            FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl2']).delete().then((value){
                                                              FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(data.docs[index]['PhotoUrl']).delete();
                                                            });
                                                          });
                                                          myTransaction.delete(snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference);
                                                        }).then((value) {
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            showSpinner = false;
                                                          });
                                                          showToast(message: 'Deleted Successfully', color: Colors.green);
                                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                                        });
                                                      },
                                                      dialogTitle: "Delete",
                                                      dialogContent: "Do you really want to delete ${data.docs[index]['Name']} restaurant?",
                                                    );
                                                  });
                                            }
                                          },
                                          child:  const Icon(Icons.delete_outline,),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    const Divider(
                                      color: Colors.white70,
                                      height:40.0,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              }),
                        );
                      }
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried all the online solutions and nothing really working for me.
Can anyone help me please

Comment: Can you try adding `shrinkWrap: true` inside listview.builder and see if it fixes the issue

Comment: I had it but still have the error

Comment: Try to add your Inside Row widgets wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463935/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559619/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444861/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Comment: It says incorrect use if parentDataWidget

Comment: how to declare you? in this format `Row(children:[Expanded(Text('OK'),),],)`,

Comment: I actually tried also this and it still bringing the box constrains error. Can you please specified where exactly I should wrap it in the code  I sent

Comment: Make the size of  your `Column` to `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`. Add `shrinkWrap: true` to your `ListView.builder`

Comment: Try my below answer hope its help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formated code hope its help to you. add your Inside `Column` widgets wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible`

```
 Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children:  [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('Hello Flutter'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```