# Can't get text to wrap correctly in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following issue
[image]

I'm trying to get the text to wrap under the dog type, I tried to wrap the text, flexible but it's not working it's in a row not sure why it's not working here is my code

```
Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
                    child: FaIcon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.cubes,
                      size: 24,
                      color: primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Dog Type: ',
                    style: AppStyles.dogProfileBodyLabelStyle,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    dogInfo.dogType!.join(", "),
                    style: AppStyles.dogProfileBodyTextStyle,
                    maxLines: 5,
                    softWrap: true,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
```

To be clear I want it to wrap under the Dog Type, not like the following
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you.Try to add your Inside Row widgets wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463935/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559619/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444861/13997210) hope its helpful to you

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 24,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
            'Dog Type: ',
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                'dogInfo.dogType!.join(", ")dogInfo.dogType!.join(", ")',
                maxLines: 5,
                softWrap: true,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Result screen->[image]

Comment: So not what I want I want it to wrap under the Dog Type

Comment: @AlmogKoren what do you exact want

Comment: It needs to wrap under Dog Type,

Comment: you want to display description below of the  dog type?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I already mentioned the same thing.

Comment: yes, its needs to wrap and then go all the way under

Answer (score 0):

Wrap

```
Text(
  dogInfo.dogType!.join(", "),
  ...
)
```

in an `Expanded` or `Flexible` widget:

```
Expanded(
  child: Text(
    dogInfo.dogType!.join(", "),
    ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: that does not work, you get this https://imgur.com/a/WoYhCZK

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, bottom: 4.0),
                child: FaIcon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.cubes,
                  size: 24,
                  color: primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              const Text(
                'Dog Type: ',
                style: AppStyles.dogProfileBodyLabelStyle,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
              Expanded(           //Wrap Text Widget with Expanded Widget
                child: Text(
                       dogInfo.dogType!.join(", "),
                       style: AppStyles.dogProfileBodyTextStyle,
                       maxLines: 5,
                       softWrap: true,
                       overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
```

or Use `RichText` Widget..

```
RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                        children: [
                          const TextSpan(text: 'Dog Type: '),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: dogInfo.dogType!.join(", "),
                            style:
                                const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF003764)),
                          )
                        ]),
                  ),
```