# Vertical viewport was given unbounded height flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

this is my code:

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(children: [
       Card(
          child: Row(
             children: [
                 ListTile(
                     title: Text(publicacion.title),
                    subtitle: Text(publicacion.body),
                 )
             ],
          )),
     ]);
  }
```

Surely it is some overflow, but I couldn't fix it, I can't find the way .. I tried to implement ListView.builder, but I wouldn't be knowing where to fit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add your Inside Row widgets wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463935/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559619/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444861/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Refer `Expanded` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

```
    ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                            'publicacion.titlepublicacion.titlepublicacion.titlepublicacion.titlepublicacion.titlepublicacion.title'),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            'publicacion.bodypublicacion.titlepublicacion.titlepublicacion.titlepublicacion.titlepublicacion.titlepublicacion.title'),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

The Row widget is creating this problem, just remove Row Widget and it should work fine.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(children: [
      Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(publicacion.title),
            subtitle: Text(publicacion.body),
          )),
    ]);
  }
```