# flutter error: A RenderFlex overflowed by 1088 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### I am using two text in side a column, one text field is long then I got this error "A RenderFlex overflowed by 1088 pixels on the right."

I am using two text in side a column, one text field is long then I got this error "A RenderFlex overflowed by 1088 pixels on the right."
How to fix it?
[image]

this is my code

```
import 'package:cwc/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class EvSpeakers extends StatefulWidget {
  final eventsListDetails;
  const EvSpeakers({Key? key, this.eventsListDetails}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EvSpeakers> createState() => _EvSpeakersState();
}

class _EvSpeakersState extends State<EvSpeakers> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
            child: Text(
              'Speakers & Moderators',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Color(0xff444444)),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
            child:
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount:widget.eventsListDetails.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Row(
                  children: [
                   widget.eventsListDetails[index]['image'] == null ? Image.asset(
                      'assets/herogirl.png',
                      width: 100,
                      height: 120,
                    ):Image.network(
                     imgBaseUrl+'${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['image']}',
                     width: 100,
                     height: 120,
                   ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 14,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['name']}',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff158998)),
                        ),
                        Text(
                        "${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}",
                         style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 12, color: Color(0xff444444)), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 2,
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap your widget inside Expanded or Flexible widget and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your widget inside Expanded or Flexible:

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Image.network(
        'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png',
        width: 100,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              ' {widget.eventsListDetails[index][ name ]}',
            ),
            Text(
              " {widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}{widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}{widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}{widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}",
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 3,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Your Result screen->  [image]

Try to add your Inside Row widgets, wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible` Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463935/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559619/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444861/13997210)

Answer (score 1):

Try constraining your text's width by wrapping it in a `SizedBox` and giving it a fixed width.

```dart
      SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        child: Text(
          "${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}",
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(fontSize: 12, color: Color(0xff444444)),
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the column with Expanded/Flexible widget.

```
Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['name']}',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff158998)),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}",
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                fontSize: 12, color: Color(0xff444444)), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 2,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
```

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EvSpeakers extends StatefulWidget {
  final eventsListDetails;
  const EvSpeakers({Key? key, this.eventsListDetails}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EvSpeakers> createState() => _EvSpeakersState();
}

class _EvSpeakersState extends State<EvSpeakers> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
            child: Text(
              'Speakers & Moderators',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Color(0xff444444)),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
              child:
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount:widget.eventsListDetails.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Row(
                  children: [
                    widget.eventsListDetails[index]['image'] == null ? Image.asset(
                      'assets/herogirl.png',
                      width: 100,
                      height: 120,
                    ):Image.network(
                      imgBaseUrl+'${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['image']}',
                      width: 100,
                      height: 120,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 14,
                    ),
                

Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['name']}',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff158998)),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}",
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 12, color: Color(0xff444444)), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 2,
                      )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
             Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['name']}',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xff158998)),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                       Text(
                        "${widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}",
                         style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 12, color: Color(0xff444444)), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 2,
                        ),),
                      ],
                    )
```